# Passing custom text to new Facebook Sharer button

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I need to pass some AngularJS variables from my application to the new Facebook sharer button, I'm using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1438439249728371";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And this:

```
 <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://mySite" data-type="button">     </div>
```

Where can I place my custom text to share in the dialog?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Sharer** wont allow that. It'll fetch the og tags from the link and fill the contents in the dialog.

If you want to add cutomized description/picture/caption you should instead use **[Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog)**.

You can use the direct URL to invoke feed dialog:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
 app_id=1438439249728371
 &display=popup
 &caption={caption}
 &link={link-to-share}
 &description={description}
 &redirect_uri={redirect-url-to-your-site}
```

You can check all available parameters [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using the wrong widget, do you know some tutorial to integrate the feed dialog in a website?

Comment: I've mentioned the link in the answer already : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog :)

Comment: Im getting this error:
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: You are using display type "popup " on the domain "www.facebook.com", which is invalid. You should access a different domain (m.facebook.com, www.facebook.com), or use one of the following supported display types: page, popup, iframe
with the popup parameter, any ideas why?
If I remove it everything works fine

Comment: This may work for the time being but the Feed Dialog has been deprecated so you should instead rely on the Share Dialog with OpenGraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Facebook SDK for JavaScript you have to use the parameter *quote*

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: window.location.href,
    quote: "Your Custom Text"
  }, function(response){});
```